# Using SuperTest/Protractor on unsecure HTTPS

Tags: javascript, protractor, api-testing, chromedriver, chrome

I am trying to run automated API tests on localhost with an invalid cert.

Is there a chromeOption equivalent to "Proceed Anyway" that I can pass to the tests so they can get a response from the url?

Right now I am manually testing the API via Postman (after using Proceed Anyway in Chrome), so the API itself does work, but the automation cannot get a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is works for me (in python):

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors"])
webdriver_instance = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168407/unsupported-command-line-flag-ignore-certificate-errors

Answer (score 1):

As this is tagged with `protractor`, this is how you allow "unsecure HTTPS" via Protractor config:

In case of Firefox:

```
capabilities: { 
  browserName: 'firefox', 
  marionette: true, 
  acceptInsecureCerts: true
}
```

In case of Chrome (not tested and may not work as is, https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/847):

```
capabilities: { 
  browserName: 'chrome', 
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
  }
}
```